# Error with removeAt java arraylist android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I received an error from Google Play console:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: my_package, PID: 19868
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:405)
    at my_package.notepad.utils_adapters.NotesAdapter.removeItem(NotesAdapter.kt:251)
    at my_package.notepad.utils_adapters.NotesAdapter.access$removeItem(NotesAdapter.kt:25)
    at my_package.notepad.utils_adapters.NotesAdapter$deleteNote$1.onResponse(NotesAdapter.kt:231)
```

I understand that the app tries to work with wrong index and as a result it receives the crash. The problem is placed at this method:

```
private fun removeItem(position: Int) {
        records.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, records.size)
    }
```

this method can be called when the used tries to remove an item from the certain list. I tried to replace `removeAt` by `remove` but I got a strict suggestion to use `removeAt`. Maybe I can check when position doesn't equal to -1 or this is a bad idea?

### UPDATE

remove item method call:

```
private fun deleteNote(id: Int?, context: Context, position: Int) {
        Singleton.apiService().deleteNote("Bearer " + context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", ""), id).enqueue(object : Callback<NoteAction> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NoteAction>, response: Response<NoteAction>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    removeItem(position)
                } else {
                    try {
                        val jObjError = JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull<ResponseBody>(response.errorBody()).string())
                        Singleton.error["message"] = jObjError.getString("message")
                        Singleton.error["request_no"] = "19"
                        Singleton.workingWithErrors(Singleton.error, context)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {

                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NoteAction>, t: Throwable) {
            }

        })
```

Comment: Check if `position` is valid at all (`-1` is never a valid index in a `Collection`)...

Comment: can you please post removeItem(-) method call

Comment: @deHaar, what means `is valid  at all`?

Comment: It means checking if this `int` is a valid index for a data structure... I have never heard of one having negative indexes, so check if `position` is negative **and** check if `position` is less than the length of the data structure. No idea why it is `-1` here... Seems like it had that value already when passed to `deleteNote(...)`.

Comment: @deHaar, why I have to check if position if less then the length of the data sctucture?

Comment: You are well advised to do so because you can have an index that is greater than the greatest one the data structure has, which would lead to an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, too, just at the opposite end of the data structure. Examle: Imagine an `int[] arr = new int[1];` with a single slot for an `int`, then the only valid index will be `0`, which is less than the length of the array (`1`) and not negative. If you try accessing `arr[-1]` or `arr[1]` you will get such an `Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking position inclusive with collections before perform delete operation.

```
private fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    if(position < 0 || position >= records.size)
        return

    records.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, records.size)
}
```